# Extract string between two characters in bash

Tags: string, bash, sed, awk

I have a string formatted as below

```
Walk Off the Earth - Somebody That I Used to Know
[playing] #36/37   1:04/4:05 (26%)
volume: n/a   repeat: off   random: on    single: off   consume: off
```

Now, from the above string I need to extract `36` from `#36/37`.

First thing I did was to extract `#36/37` from second line using

```
echo "above mentioned string" | awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'
```

Now, I want to extract `36` from the above extracted part for that I did

```
echo `#36/37` | sed -e 's/\//#/g' | awk -F "#" '{print $2}'
```

which gave me `36` as my outptut.

But, I feel that using both `sed and awk` just to extract text from `#36/37` is but of a overkill. So, is there any better or shorter way to achieve this.

Comment: Is your input really a string, or is it a stream?

Comment: @kojiro: Basically its a stream. You can see it is the output of `mpc status` command but I am wondering what difference does it make.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the field on the pound and slash characters into an array and retrieve the required element.

```
awk 'NR==2 {split($2, arr, "[#/]"); print arr[2]}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I found your solution close to mine but can you explain to me what `[#/]` is doing or even better if you can point me to documentation.

Comment: @Noob: See [`man grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) in the section "Character Classes and Bracket Expressions".

Answer (score 4):

This answer takes advantage of bash's built-in extended regular-expression syntax using the `=~` test operator. (I say `test`, but don't expect it to work with the `test` command. It only works with the `[[` keyword.)

```
mini:~ michael$ cat foo
Walk Off the Earth - Somebody That I Used to Know
[playing] #36/37   1:04/4:05 (26%)
volume: n/a   repeat: off   random: on    single: off   consume: off

mini:~ michael$ [[ $(<foo) =~ \#[[:digit:]]{2} ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]#\#}"
36
```

When you boil it down, this is simply a regular expression that matches the two digits after a pound sign, and saves them in the zeroth element of the `BASH_REMATCH` array.

Comment: Wow a fancy solution. I would love understand how it is working.

Comment: @Noob: updated with explanation. (But perhaps now it's a little clearer why it matters whether the input is a real string or a stream. It would be a little more cumbersome to use this syntax on a stream.)

Comment: Damn, I completely forgot about bash regexes! Thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 3):

One way using `sed` assuming `infile` has the content of the question. In second line match any characters until `#`, then save any numbers in group 1, and substitute the complete line with this group `\1`. The `-n` switch avoids print anything unless indicated with a `p` instruction in the code.

```
sed -ne '2 { s/^[^#]*#\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/; p; q }' infile
```

Output:

```
36
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/.*#\([0-9]*\)\/[0-9]*.*/\1/p;d' file
36
```

Comment: Although it'll pick up any album or song titles that happen to have something like #1/2 in them. Or even a `#/`, although that would be rare.

Answer (score 3):

```
input | while read playing numbers rest
do
  if [[ $playing = "[playing]" ]]; then
    t="${numbers:1}"
    echo "${t%/*}"
  fi
done
```

Bash default split is by whitespace, so what you get in the second field (numbers) is just that numbers. The rest is the use of bash parameter expansion operators to get at the portion of interest: remove the first character and remove the suffix starting with "/"

Comment: This would seem to output 'ff', '36' and '/a'

Comment: there is always a place for another `test "$playing" = '[playing]' || continue`

Comment: And it uses only shell builtins, which might be faster and cheaper than fork and exec of external programs. Depends on the amount of input, of course. And we are lucky to have the input this simple

Comment: I still think your answer should itself be complete, or at least explain what it's missing. Even after editing it, this answer outputs 'ff' and '36' and potentially some blank lines.

Comment: @fork0 I wouldn't have made the comment without trying the code first. http://dpaste.com/768337/

Comment: @kojiro: You missed the `test "$playing" = '[playing]' || continue`

Comment: @fork0 Having it in the comments isn't sufficient. I mean you needed to edit your answer to include that part. So I edited it for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '2s/.*\#\([0-9]*\)\/.*/\1/p'
```

This suppresses everything but the second line, then echos the digits between `#` and `/`

Answer (score 3):

This would solve your problem.

```
awk -F'[#/]' 'NR==2{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a script which output the string between the first and last character. To solve you're problem, you can use the following commands combined with this script.

```
echo '[playing] #36/37   1:044:05 (26%)' | cut -d' ' -f2 | ./cut_between.sh -f '#' -l '/'
```

You can download this script on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/ahaitoute/5004850).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without any external program with BASH-internal string operations like this:

```
string="[playing] #36/37   1:04/4:05 (26%)"
part=${string##*#};number=${part%%/*}
echo "$number"
```